# How to open a new tab in the browser using the package:js in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to open a new tab

I can do so by using dart:js

```
js.context.callMethod('open',
          ['$url', '_blank']);
```

But the above approach gave me this warning

```
Avoid using web-only libraries outside Flutter web plugin packages.dartavoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
```

Then I read about javascript interoperability with dart [here](https://dart.dev/web/js-interop) at dart official documentation page.

It suggests to use the package `js: ^0.6.3` ( [link](https://pub.dev/packages/js) ) instead of `dart:js`

The problem is that I don't know how I can use `js: ^0.6.3` to open a new tab in the browser. I couldn't find much documentation or tutorial.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are ok with the idea of using other packages, you can try `import 'dart:html' as html;` `html.window.open($url,"_blank");`

Comment: It is giving me the similar warning

Comment: Have you tried this package ?? 
url_launcher : https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I'm not looking for an alternative, I'm looking for away to implement it using the package:js  if there's any. Also I'm looking forward to use this package to implement other javascript related functionalities as well. So a kickstart guide regarding this will help me.